# Django Celery cannot connect to remote RabbitMQ on EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, celery

I created a rabbitmq cluster on two instances on EC2. My django app uses celery for async tasks which in turn uses RabbitMQ for message queue.

Whenever I start celery with the command:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO
```

OR

```
python manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO
```

I keep getting following error message related to remote RabbitMQ:

```
[2015-05-19 08:58:47,307: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://myuser:**@<ip-address>:25672/myvhost/: Socket closed.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

I set permissions using:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

and then restarted `rabbitmq-server` on both the cluster nodes. However, it didn't help.

In log file, I see few entries like below:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 19-May-2015::08:14:41 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1981.0> (<ip-address>:38471 -> <ip-address>:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 19-May-2015::08:14:44 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1981.0> (<ip-address>:38471 -> <ip-address>:5672):
{handshake_error,opening,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "access to vhost 'myvhost' refused for user 'myuser'",
                             'connection.open'}}
```

Comment: Are the python workers and the RabbitMQ in different instances?

Comment: Yes. Celery worker is on my laptop and rabbitmq is on EC2

Comment: Ok, the problem is your instance is behind a firewall in EC2 and it's not accepting requests from outside.

Comment: But in the security groups I have kept ports 5672, 4369 and 25672 open.

Comment: @dgil Edited the question and added the error message I see in logs

Comment: Have you changed the configuration of RabbitMQ to listen outside localhost?

Comment: @dgil nope. Searching for the change I am supposed to make to the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had not created appropriate configuration files. In my case (Ubuntu 14.04), I had to create below two configuration files:

```
$ cat /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=<ip_of_ec2_instance>
```

`<ip_of_ec2_instance>` has to be the internal IP that EC2 uses. Not the public IP that one uses to ssh into the instance. It can be obtained using `ip a` command.

```
$ cat /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
[
    {mnesia, [{dump_log_write_threshold, 1000}]},
    {rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [25672]}]},
    {rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}
].
```

I think the line `{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [25672]}]},` was one of the most important piece of configuration that I was missing.

Thanks @dgil for the initial troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` contains an entry for `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` to bind it only to localhost. Removing the `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` entry from the config binds the port to all [network inferfaces](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/464311/open-port-5672-tcp-for-access-to-rabbitmq-on-mac

Comment: There's no such directory under `/usr/local/etc`.

Comment: The path I wrote is in Mac. I guess you use Linux then. Can you check if is it in  `/usr/local/rabbitmq` instead, please?

Comment: Can't see there either. Man page for `rabbitmq-env.conf` on my Ubuntu 14.04 system says the path is `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`. The file doesn't exist so I guess I will just create a new one.

Comment: Added the entry `NODE_IP_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0` in the configuration file. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have a Linux machine now to test it, sorry. I found that in Ubuntu the default file is in `/etc/default/rabbitmq-server`

Comment: From `netstat -nltp` output I can see that port 25672 listens on 0.0.0.0. But it isn't helping. So I think we are past the firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered. but just leaving notes with a similar issue i faced should anybody else find it useful

I have a `flask app` running on `ec2` with `amqp as a broker on port 5672` and `ec2 elasticcache memcached as a backend`. The amqp broker had trouble picking up tasks that were  getting fired - so i resolved it by fixing as such

Assuming you have `rabbitmq-server` installed (`sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`), add the user and set the properties as such

```
sudo add_user username password
set_permissions username ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

restart server: `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart`

In your flask app for the celery configuration

```
broker_url=amqp://username:password@localhost:5672// (Set as above)
backend=cache+memcached://(ec2 cache url):11211/
```

(The cache+memcached:// tripped me up - without it i kept getting an import error (cannot import module)

Open up the port 5672 on your ec2 instance in the security group.

Now if you fire up your celery worker, it should pick up the the tasks that get fired and store the results on your memcached server